# how to prevent overlapping sounds on multiple notifications

Tags: android, audio, notifications, android-notifications

In my android app is a very common scenario to receive multiple notifications at the same time.
Each notification can have a custom sound (set by the user) to recognize what type of notification is without looking at the status bar.
The problem is that when multiple notifications are sent at the same time, the sounds overlap themselves and the result is an unpleasant noise besides to completely break the feature to recognize the type of notifications just hearing the sound.

Is there a way to queue the notification sounds? Alternatively, can I send a notification only when another one finished to play his sound?

Answer (score 0):

If you are you using the SoundPool class you can setMaxStreams() to 1 to avoid multiple sounds from playing. Additionally, the Soundpool class allows you to set a priority for each notification sound, so it can know which sound to play when there are multiple sounds trying to play at the same time. Unfortunately, Soundpool does not support queues of any kind.

Alternatively, if you are using MediaPlayer to play sounds, you can use the onCompletionListener. However, it's not recommended to use the MediaPlayer for notification sounds as MediaPlayer was meant to be used for longer audio files.